# Why does not the GAS assembler cmp instruction obey its syntax: source, dest?

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86-64, att, gnu-assembler

In GAS, `subq %rbx, %rax` means subtract `rbx` from `rax`, but the cmpq does not work this way. `cmpq %rbx, %rax` means subtract `rax` from `rbx` as the Intel syntax.
This is annoying. This is the first thing I have noticed. Are there are more that you know of?

Here is the code to confirm what I observed:

```
    .globl _start

# How many data elements we have
.section .text
_start:
movq $3, %rax
movq $4, %rbx
cmpq %rax, %rbx
jb rdiis1
ja rdiis2
rdiis1:
movq $1, %rdi
jmp end
rdiis2:
movq $2, %rdi
# We're done - 
end:
movq $60, %rax
syscall
```

I compiled and ran code in linux. echo $? returns 2.

Comment: With comparison you don't really have a "source" and "destination" arguments, like for subtraction.

Comment: `cmp` works the same as `sub`. Your code demonstrates it. 4 is the second operand which is above 3. `4-3=1` no carry. Note you can can simply put a `sub` in there and see the result stays 2.

Comment: Your text has `cmpq %rbx, %rax`, but your code has `cmpq %rax, %rbx` — that's adding to confusion; which one are you asking about?

Comment: @Jester. My code proves what I say: `cmpq %rax, %rbx` = `4 - 3` = 1, jb branches to `ridiis2`. But I expect `3 - 4`, which is the way `subq` works.

Comment: @Erik Eidt.  I meant `cmpq` follows Intel syntax, not the usual AT&T syntax of left to right.

Comment: You are wrong about `sub` then. That also does `4 - 3`. You can literally change the `cmp` into a `sub` and see the result is still 2. Or use a debugger and see that `sub` does `4 - 3 = 1` as well. Intel syntax `sub` works in reverse that subtracts from the first operand, not the second.

Comment: @Jester. I know I am right because this is the way `sub` works in the GAS assembler. It is also stated in the book on x64 assembly by Jonathan Bartlette. However, when I implemented the `divq` instruction by repeated subtractions, I found that `cmpq` does not work like `sub` so I asked here. I am using the SASM IDE so I can see that value changes in the registers with each instruction.

Comment: Have you actually tried to change the `cmp` into a `sub`? Just swap those 3 letters and test. `cmp` and `sub` work the same.

Comment: Correct.  The only difference between `cmp` and `sub` is that the former discards the difference while `sub` stores it in the destination operand.

Comment: Yes. I was wrong. `sub` subtracts second operand from first operand. Only difference is it stores the result in the second operand. Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: `sub` and `cmp` always subtract from the destination operand. In at&t that's the second operand, in intel that's the first. It's always `dst = dst - src`. In at&t you write `src, dst` in intel `dst, src`.

Comment: Why didnt they implement sub like `mov`? It would be easy to remember, right? `subq operand 1, operand 2` reads  `subtract operand 1` from `operand 2` just like normal English.

Comment: AT&T syntax *does* work like that.  `sub op1, op2` subtracts op1 from op2 (result in op2), like Jester just said.  Single-step it in a debugger.  x86 doesn't have a reverse-subtract (like ARM `rsb`), only instructions that subtract from the destination (`sub` and `cmp`, with `cmp` not updating the destination).  Intel's manual documents this, but with the operand order opposite of AT&T.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sub

Comment: Yes. I got mixed up with the Intel syntax again. This is frustrating. If only I had not studied masm.

Comment: you mention "`jb` branches to `ridiis2`" —  but the code has `ja rdiis2`.

Comment: Btw, it is better to use a single branch instead of two branches.  In your construct, you don't need the `jb` or the label `rdiis1:`, the `ja rdiis2` is sufficient.

Comment: Also, fyi, your two branches (`jb`, `ja`) aren't opposites, as taken together, neither accounts for equality: the opposite of > is <=; the opposite of < is >= (and vice versa).